# Reading SQL Server Column in an Array or List

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to know how to copy the values contained in a column in sql server database into an `Array` or a `List`?
I'm using `C#` in a Web Application Project(ASP.NET)...

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can retrieve the datas in column to string ,then use split function and then for loop to store it in array

Comment: How are you planning to use the data in the resulting array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("server=(local);database=pubs;Integrated Security=SSPI"))  {
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from authors", cnn); 
 DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
 da.Fill(ds, "authors"); 

 List<string> authorNames = new List<string>();
 foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["authors"].Rows)
 {
   authorNames.Add(row["name"].ToString());
 }
}
```

Very basic example to fill author names into List.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/

Answer (score 1):

First you have to fill records in dataTable and then iterate through all rows of dataTable and add one by one each record to array list.
Check this:
http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1864.htm

```
ArrayList obj = new ArrayList();
for(int x= 0;x<dtGet.Rows.Count;x++)
{
 obj.Add(dtGet.Rows[x]['col_name']);
}
```