# C# - store data from database in 2 column list

Tags: c#, string, list, npgsql

```
    public static List<string>[] ColumnToList2(string table, List<string>[]data, NpgsqlConnection ncon)
    {
        using (ncon)
        {
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, name FROM " + table + "", ncon);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "" + table + "");
            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["" + table + ""].Rows)
            {
                //Testing area
                //Console.WriteLine(row["id"].ToString());
                //Console.WriteLine(row["name"].ToString());

                data[0].Add(row[0].ToString());
                data[1].Add(row[1].ToString());                    
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Hello again! This time i want to ask advice for searching id from value, then storing both columns in list array.
When i test input in console there is what i want, but when try to see after input in list, there isnt the resut i wanted (id name - list)
Here goes definition of variables:

```
        List<string>[] data_array = new List<string>[];
        datu_array[0]=new List<string>();
        datu_array[1]=new List<string>();
```

When i try to see output through console, there is and error - that i havent defined array size

I hope u can help me solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this: `"" + table + ""`? `table` is already a `string`.

Comment: Why don't you return directly the DataTable without all this coding? The DataTable contains already your data and can be addressed  like an array but has many advantages.

Comment: That means, i can just use Datatable, and extract information out of it?

Comment: Do you really want a `List<string>[]` instead of `List<string[]>`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter there is difference in it? I just went through lot of stackowerflow materials, there was one link : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572101/reading-sql-server-column-in-an-array-or-list) , but i need 2 values in it, id and its name. Cause when i choose name in combobox, then i get its id, for input in database.

Comment: Of course they are different. `List<string>[]` is an array of lists whereas `List<string[]>` is one list of arrays which is similar to a `DataTable` which has rows and every row fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you actually want a `List<string[]>` instead of   `List<string>[]`. So one list and for every row a `string[]` with all  columns as strings.

You could use LINQ:

```
List<string[]> data = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
 .Select(row => row.ItemArray
    .Select(col => col.ToString())
    .ToArray())
 .ToList();
```

But why don't you stay with the `DataTable` which has some advantages over the list, for example the columns which you can either access via ordinal index or via name.

Comment: so, each record in database, is stored as string[], that means id and its name is at one line or coulmn name all records on one string and all ids at other?

Comment: Every row contains all fields/columns of the table, so in your case the columns `Id` and `Name`. You can access them either via index or name. So if you want the id and name of the first row: `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("Name")` or `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<int>("Id")`

Comment: Thanks again! I can also assign them to variables?

Answer (score 4):

Arrays need to be assigned a size when they are instantiated:

```
List<string>[] data_array = new List<string>[2];
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasnt sure, if that was correct, but when i tried lenght 2, then when i was looking through array with foreach, it showed 2 records only.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, I would suggest that you use a dictionary instead of a List of string arrays.

Comment: I just need this, for input form in database, where i have 2 comboboxes, where i choose input values, but from database side, i need there not values, but their IDs.

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you just need to store a key that references a value, which is what a dictionary is designed to do. Perhaps I am mistaken, but at any rate here is the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx